# What's the etymological connection between substance and understand?

Tags: etymology

Does the word SUBSTANCE come from the word UNDERSTAND? Or vice versa

Sub (under) stand (stance)

If so, what is the etymological relationship/history?

If not, is it a coincidence?

Comment: It is expected that a question show some research in the post. A good place to start might be on [Etymonline.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=substance%2C+understand)

Comment: I have already researched into it and from the site you mentioned. However it's fairly inconclusive. And whether substance derives from "stand under" or "understand".

Comment: Stance means position, standing. They both started from stand.

Comment: There is no direct etymological connection between *substance* and *understand*. They both come from the proto-indoeuropean root [**steh-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/steh%E2%82%82-).  meaning *to stand*.  But *understand* comes from it through proto-Germanic and Old English, and *substance* comes from it through proto-Italic, Latin and French. It's somewhat surprising that these two words took very different routes to modern English, and that their pronunciations are fairly close.